# Django, topic model with subtopics

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, one-to-many

i wanted to create a topic model.
this model would have a foreign key, non required, to the topic above it
for example:

iphone has a foreign key to apple

but what do i do if i want apple to be linked to all of its sub elements

apple to iPhone
apple to mac

i know that there are many to many fields, but how exactly would you apply them to this 
situation

furthermore mac or iPhone might even have more sub elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look at the documentation for `related_name`.  Basically Django does this for you.  For example:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    master_topic = models.ForeignKey('self',
                     null=True,
                     blank=True,
                     related_name="sub_topics")
```

Then access this code:

```
apple = Topic.objects.filter(tag='Apple')
sub_topics = apple.sub_topics.all() ## Gets all sub_topics.
```

Comment: seems to be the right choice, but one thing, as of now when i try to create a new topic i need to select a master topic, but there is none since i didn't create one yet, ill just do required=false to fix this?

Comment: Should work.  I forgot to add that into the model definition.